# Why `\multicolumn` and `\hdotsfor` do not work as expected?

Tags: formatting, matrices, multicolumn

I have the determinant

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
a      & b      & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
a      & b      & c      & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\dotfill} \\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & y      & z
\end{vmatrix}.
$$
\end{document}
```

I would like to have all the dots on each line merged in a line of the corresponding length. Firstly, I tried to achieve this by using `\multicolumn{...}{c}{\dotfill}` as follows:

```
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
a & b & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\dotfill} \\
a & b & c & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\dotfill} \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\dotfill} \\
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\dotfill} & y & z
\end{vmatrix},
$$
```

which is not what I need. Then I thought of `\hdotsfor`,

```
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
a & b & \hdotsfor{4} \\
a & b & c & \hdotsfor{3} \\
\hdotsfor{6} \\
\hdotsfor{4} & y & z
\end{vmatrix},
$$
```

with the same result. However, if I add an empty line (with the corresponding `&`s), like this

```
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
 & & & & & \\[-3ex]
a & b & \hdotsfor{4} \\
a & b & c & \hdotsfor{3} \\
\hdotsfor{6} \\
\hdotsfor{4} & y & z
\end{vmatrix},
$$
```

then I obtain quite what I need, except that I have to add a negative vertical space between the empty line and the first nonempty line. By trial and error, I found that a negative space of `-3ex` is approximately what I need in this case.

My question is: why `\hdotsfor` alone does not work as I expected, and it does when I add an empty line? In case that the empty line is necessary, how can one compute the exact size of the negative skip that should be added (instead of `[-3ex]`) to get rid (visually) of the undesired space?

Comment: Could you please make your code fragments compilable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your matrix the third and fourth columns only contain material with zero natural width (but stretchable), so they contribute nothing to the alignment.

You can provide a phantom row, which is your idea; the amount of backspacing is `\normalbaselineskip`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{vmatrix}
% a phantom row
\mbox{\enspace} & \mbox{\enspace} & \mbox{\enspace} &
\mbox{\enspace} & \mbox{\enspace} & \mbox{\enspace} \\[-\normalbaselineskip]
a      & b      & \hdotsfor{4} \\
a      & b      & c      & \hdotsfor{3} \\
\hdotsfor{6} \\
\hdotsfor{4} & y & z
\end{vmatrix}
% a matrix to check the heights
\begin{vmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \end{vmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

I provided a “minimum width” of 0.5em.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Very useful and clear answer. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `nicematrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[transparent]{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{vmatrix}[margin=0.5em]
a      & b      & \ldots \\
a      & b      & c      & \ldots \\
\ldots \\
\ldots &        &        &  y & z
\end{vmatrix}
% a matrix to check the heights
\begin{vmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \end{vmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]

Or, with less space on both sides (suggestion of Sebastiano):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[transparent]{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{vmatrix}[extra-margin=0.2em,nullify-dots]
a      & b      & \ldots & \Hspace*{3.7mm}\\
a      & b      & c      & & \ldots \\
\ldots \\
\ldots &        &        & &  y & z
\end{vmatrix}
% a matrix to check the heights
\begin{vmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \end{vmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: result of the above code]

Comment: Very nice. :-) Maybe it would be better if the dots match vertically below *a*. The dots are too far to the left and they create a space excessive for the determinant.